# Categorical Grade Data (A+, B-, etc) into numerical values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` where one column is grade data. It spans from `A+`, `A`, `A-` etc. all the way down to `F`. These are in the form categories. I want to convert them efficiently into numbers, such that the best grade gets the highest number. Since there are 13 grades, `A+` should get the value of 13 and `F` should get the value of `1`.

For instance (but with categories instead of strings):

```
grades = ['A+', 'C-', 'F', 'B', 'D-']
students = ['billy', 'bob', 'joe', 'tom', 'jamal']

pd.DataFrame(columns = ['grades'], data = grades, index = students )
```

I would like to turn the `grades1` column of this `DataFrame` into numeric values ranging from `1` to `13`, corresponding to the categories of `F` and `A+` respectively. I'm not really sure how to go about this. A

EDIT: also this is is multiindex dataframe. The first index is the date, the second is the name, then the value.

Comment: You could look into pandas' category. Will write an answer tomorrow on how to do that efficient and fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do is build a dict, mapping each letter grade to a value.

You can do this explicitly:

```
gradevalues = {'A+': 13, 'A': 12, …, 'F': 1}
```

But it's probably better to do it programmatically, because less repetition means fewer places to make a typo:

```
grades = 'A+ A A- B+ B B- C+ C C- D+ D D- F'.split()
grades.reverse()
gradevalues = {grade: i for i, grade in enumerate(grades, 1)}
assert gradevalues['F'] == 1
assert gradevalues['A+'] == 13
```

Comment: Right, but this is where I'm getting stuck. How do I actually take my gradevalues dictionary, and replace the values in the original dataframe with the corresponding dictionary?

Comment: @Maher Any of the usual Pandas ways to apply a dict to a column, like `df.Grades = df.Grades.map(gradevalues))`.

Comment: ah the .map was the bit I was missing out on. Thank you for your help! Would .map() be the fastest implementation for this type of thing?

Comment: @abarnert you're right by saying you should avoid to make typos, but your solution makes the dict get generated every time you run the code, even though it's just a very much static dictionary that can be defined and will never be touched by the application. It would make much more sense to define it statically instead of programmatically.

Comment: @Adriano Generating it takes a tiny fraction of a millisecond. Doing that once per run of the program is nothing. It’s not like we’re doing this inside an inner loop that will run once per row for a billion rows. That’s like saying you shouldn’t define functions or classes because they’re always created dynamically in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your problems go away once you declare these values as Categorical items.

```
s = pd.Series(['C+', 'A+', 'D+', 'D', 'D', 'A+', 'C', 'D+', 'C+', 'A+', 'A-', 'F',
       'B', 'D+', 'D-', 'A+', 'A+', 'D-', 'A', 'B-'])
```

```
cats = 'A+ A A- B+ B B- C+ C C- D+ D D- F'.split()[::-1]
s = pd.Categorical(s, categories=cats, ordered=True)

s.codes + 1
array([ 7, 13,  4,  3,  3, 13,  6,  4,  7, 13, 11,  1,  9,  4,  2, 13, 13,
        2, 12,  8], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: I was hoping for something like this but this doesn't seem to work with my data. My original dataframe is a multiindex: the first index is date, the second index is name, and then the only value is the grade. I'm not sure if that makes a difference. Copy-pasting your method but using my DataFrame instead of s results in array([0], dtype=int8), even though there are 1444 data points.

Comment: @Maher I don't see why that should make a difference. "Doesn't seem to work" doesn't seem to tell me much, can you explain what it is you see that is the issue?

Comment: @Maher So what if you did `df['col'] = pd.Categorical(df['col'], categories=cats, ordered=True)` and then ran `df['col'].cat.codes`?